# why replacing missing value with -99999 in classification dataset

Tags: machine-learning, classification

working on classification problem, missing value denoted by '?', So why -99999?

```
df.replace('?',-99999,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what your eventual use of this data will be.  Having strings in a numerical column is not great from a data cleanliness perspective, so replacing with `np.nan` (a `float` type) or the newish `pd.NA` is probably the best idea from a data presentation standpoint.  Most models cannot make use of those values, but some can, e.g. `xgboost`.  For models that cannot handle missing values (or when you don't want the model to handle them internally), you need to decide the best way to impute.

Imputing with values outside the real data range, like -99999, is largely fine for tree models: they don't care about scale, so you're really just saying it's less than everything else.  In parametric models like logistic regression though, this will badly mess up parameter estimates, and I'd strongly advise against it.  Adding missingness indicators helps out, but still I suspect numerical issues with such large imputation values, and so mean/median or model-based imputation would be better.

Answer (score 0):

we can replace with any very big number, the only purpose of doing that is to make that an outlier, because in most cases dropping the missing values causes loss of data